# Trying to validate values inside a loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Trying to validate a multi-form data. If class "a" is checked it has to check whether class "b" is empty or not.

```js
c = 1;
d = 1;
$('.a').each(function() {
  if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
    $('.b').each(function() {
      if ($(this).val() == '') {
        err += "<p>Value Empty at row +c+</p>";
        return false;
      }
      d = d + 1;
    });
  }
  c = c + 1;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="a" name="a[]" value="Value" />&nbsp;Value</label><br> <input type="text" class="b" name="b[]" />
```

The Issue is, it validates perfectly for the first form. when it comes to second form, it checks the first value of class 'b' instead of checking second value of class 'b'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't want the `.b` loop *inside* the `.a` loop. You want a single loop handling both:

```
var checkboxes = $(".a");
var textboxes  = $(".b");
for (var n = 0; n < checkboxes.length; ++n) {
    if (checkboxes[n].checked && !textboxes[n].value.trim()) {
        err += "<p>Value Empty at row " + n + "</p>";
    }
}
```

Live Example:

```js
$("#btn").on("click", function() {
  var err = "";
  var checkboxes = $(".a");
  var textboxes  = $(".b");
  for (var n = 0; n < checkboxes.length; ++n) {
      if (checkboxes[n].checked && !textboxes[n].value.trim()) {
          err += "<p>Value Empty at row " + n + "</p>";
      }
  }
  $("#err").html(err);
});
```

```html
<label><input type="checkbox" class="a" name="a[]" value="Value" />&nbsp;Value</label><br> <input type="text" class="b" name="b[]" />
<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="a" name="a[]" value="Value" />&nbsp;Value</label><br> <input type="text" class="b" name="b[]" />
<br>
<label><input type="checkbox" class="a" name="a[]" value="Value" />&nbsp;Value</label><br> <input type="text" class="b" name="b[]" />
<br>
<input type="button" id="btn" value="Check">
<div id="err"></div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

---

A couple of notes:

- When you use `[n]` to index into a jQuery object, you get the raw DOM element at that position. When you have the raw element, there's no need for `.is(":checked")`, just use the `checked` property on the element itself. (So: `checkboxes[n].checked` instead of `$(checkboxes[n]).is(":checked")` or `checkboxes.eq(n).is(":checked")`.)
- Similarly, `input` elements have their own `value` property, no need to wrap them in an jQuery object just to call `val()`.
- My code above assumes that an input containing only whitespace should be considered empty. It does that with [`String#trim`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim), which was introduced in ES5 (2009). If you need to support seriously obsolete browsers like IE8, you may need a polyfill for it.

Comment: @crowder thanks for the solution. it really solved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the code

```
$(".b")...
```

it checks all inputs with class b, but you only want the related one.  The key is determining *how* they are related.  It could be they are in a parent `div` or they could be matched using `data-` attributes, or could simply be the "next" input.

Your example HTML only shows one 'pair' of `.a` and `.b`, so if we expand that pair to multiple pairs, eg grouped in a 'group' div, you can then use `.closest(".group")` to find the containing `div` and then the related `.b` within that div:

```js
$("#validate").click(function() {

  var c = 1;
  var d = 1;
  var err = "";
  $('.a').each(function() {
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      // only find the related `.b`
      //$('.b').each(function() {
      $(this).closest(".group").find(".b").each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == '') {
          err += "<p>Value Empty at row " + c + "</p>";
          return false;
        }
        d = d + 1;
      });
    }
    c = c + 1;
  });
  console.log("c:", c, "d:", d, err);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='group'>
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="a" name="a[]" value="Value" />
      &nbsp;Value
    </label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="b" name="b[]" />
</div>
<div class='group'>
  <label>
      <input type="checkbox" class="a" name="a[]" value="Value" />
      &nbsp;Value
    </label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="b" name="b[]" />
</div>
<button id='validate' type='button'>validate</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

When you're doing `$('.b').each(function(){})` it's finding all the elements with class `.b` again/each time. Hence checking for first element again.

One solution would be to first find all the elements and then run the loop and use index to find the elements

```
as = $(".a");
bs = $(".b");

for(var i = 0; i < as.length; i++){
  a = as[i];
  b = bs[i];
  if($(a).is(':checked')){
    if($(b).val() === ''){
      err += "<p>Value Empty at row +c+</p>";
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

Or structure your markup a in such a way where all the related elements with class `a` & `b` are put inside a div.
    You can find all the `.a` and while looping you'll find all the `.b` inside the parent div

```
<div class='wrapper-related-fields'>
  <label><input type="checkbox" class="a" name="a[]" value="Value" />&nbsp;Value</label>
  <br>
  <input type="text" class="b" name="b[]" />
</div>

$('.a').each(function(){
  if($(this).is(':checked')){
    // Find the parent wrapper
    wrapper = $(this).closest(".wrapper-related-fields");

    // find all the .b elements inside wrapper
    $(warpper).find('.b').each(function(){
      if($(this).val() == '')
      {
        err += "<p>Value Empty at row +c+</p>";
        return false;
      }
      d = d + 1;
    });
  }
  c = c + 1;
});
```